# NCurses – getstr() and function keys

Tags: c++, c, ncurses

**My situation:**

- In **ncurses mode** I have window *contentWin*.
- From this window I want read "string" by this code.

---

```
char str [41];
wgetnstr(contentWin, str, 40);
```

I want be able to **catch F2 key** in this moment. I think about catch character, then compare and then (if != F2) put it in to the terminal and **str** without using **wgetnstr()**.

Is there different (easier) way? Thanks :-).

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of. You might want to create your own function that is similar to `wgetnstr()` that does the checking for F2 etc....

You could base the function on the following code which captures F2.

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{   
    int ch;

    initscr();          /* Start curses mode        */
    raw();              /* Line buffering disabled  */
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);       /* We get F1, F2 etc..      */
    noecho();           /* Don't echo() while we do getch */

    while( (ch = wgetch(stdscr) ) != KEY_F(2))
    {
        printw("Key code: %u Key: %c\n", ch, ch);
        refresh();          /* Print it on to the real screen */
    }
    endwin();           /* End curses mode        */

    printf("F2 pressed .. program exiting\n");

    return(0);
}
```